# Looping Queries in Access

Tags: mysql, sql, vba, loops

I have 15 similar tables, with changes in data. 
Table 1= Department, name, ID,sales,stock....
table 2= Department, name, ID,sales,stock....
...so on

The query that I have compares table 1 and table 2  on ID and find changes in Sales, stock and other fields with union I do this again this time selecting table 2 and table 3 and so on.

Every day I have to update the query with new table names as the system generates new table names everyday. so currently I have to edit the table name in query comparing table 1 and 2, comparing table 2 and 3, and so on till all the 15 tables are compared all the results and clustered in a new table with union.

What I would like to do is to have a dynamic query that compare table A and table B where A and B changes and have this query nested in a vba loop that passes the table names to query.

I would also like VBA to identify the names of the new tables and so it can pass that to query every time the loop runs.

Any help would be appreciated.

Many Thanks

Comment: Your question seems to be very vague. Could you update with some examples?

Answer (score 0):

You'll just have to write a procedure to catch the names of the tables when they're generated, then dynamically build a string and execute it for each pairing.  But, ask a general question and get a general answer...